# How to streamline connections to my Google Cloud VPN to approved Ip addresses

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, site-to-site-vpn

Please I need assistance on streamlining connections to my cloud VPN as I am a developer with little networking knowledge.
After back and forth with I was able to setup VPN connection from a vendor location to my company’s server on Google Cloud Compute. However, I am extremely worried about incurred cost. I saw 154548 and 10570 hits on the firewall from unknown sources.
Please what configurations do I need to setup to only allow traffic from approved Ip addresses
Thank you for the Support in advance and I would appreciate a timely feedback.

Comment: could you specify what kind of attempt?

Answer (score 0):

According to [VPN Pricing](https://cloud.google.com/network-connectivity/docs/vpn/pricing) you won't be incurring in any cost because of those failed attempts. Only the tunnel itself is billed.

Comment: Ok thanks for the insight